# Get the current liveBroadcast name for my channel's "Stream Now" stream via YouTube Live Streaming API

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-livestreaming-api

We're starting to use YouTube's Stream Now feature and noticed that while the feature has a static YouTube URL (ie: YouTube.com/channel-name/live) the broadcast/video ID changes whenever a new stream is ended and a new one is started.

Is there a way via the YouTube API to know the current liveBroadcast/video ID for my channel streaming via the Stream Now feature?

And while we are at this, is there a way that this broadcast name in the Stream Now doesn't change and always the same? This would allow reusing the same embed code for all the steams.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve the "Stream Now" Broadcast by setting **broadcastType** to **persistent** in your request to liveBroadcast/list.

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/liveBroadcasts?part=id%2Csnippet%2C%20status%2C%20contentDetails&broadcastStatus=all&broadcastType=persistent&key=[YOUR_API_KEY] HTTP/1.1

Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]
Accept: application/json
```

But after the end of a "Stream Now" stream, the broadcast is converted into a video, and you have to create a new livestream. It's not documented, but I figured out that you can do this by making a call to liveBroadcast/insert with only **"isDefaultBroadcast"** parameter, set to *true*

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/liveBroadcasts?part=id%2Csnippet%2C%20status%2C%20contentDetails&key=[YOUR_API_KEY] HTTP/1.1

Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "snippet": {
    "isDefaultBroadcast": true
  }
}
```

I hope I help you, it took me many many time to found this, because of the bad documentation of Youtube Live API...